# Sum values depending on Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table:

`Date, HoursToWork, Workers_ID, Contract_ID, ContractStartDate`

My goal is to sum all hours for the CURRENT contract since the contract can change every day a year the date goes from the 01.01. - 31.12.. There are 'n' contracts possible. We can work with the Contract_ID (if there is more than one ID, the highest ID is always the current contract) or with the ContractStartDate. The table i created (see above) has the following structure: If a worker has two contracts he has two entries for each date. One for contract 1 and one for contract 2. e.g.

```
01-01-2013, 8, 1, 1, 01.01.2013
01-01-2013, 4, 1, 2, 03.05.2013
```

Assumend the worker works 8 hours a day (not thinking about holiday or so) we would add up 8 hours for every workday till the 02.05.2013. Now the contract changes and he works 4 hours a day we start adding to the already collected hours 4 hours for every workday till the end of the year.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: "My goal is to sum all hours for the CURRENT contract" i dont know how to achieve that.

Comment: For a specified worker? For all workers? Do you want a summary for each worker? A grand total for all workers? Is there a separate table for contracts? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want a summary for a specific worker (the one who is logged into the server, i have a little script to find that out so i put 'where XXX=workers_ID' at the end). There is a separate table for contracts with contract_ID and contractStartDate. What i tried so far. I tried to accomplish the idea: Sort every entry for every day by contract_ID (if there is more than one contract id for a worker) and delete the entries after the Top1 entry, but since sql is not a 'home game' for me it ended up in a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your clarification is that you want this by user.  To get the current contract, use `row_number()` and choose the most recent `ContractId` for each user.  Then, just do the aggregation:

```
select workers_id, ContractId, ContractStartDate, SUM(HoursToWork)
from (select t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Workers_Id order by Contract_id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by workers_id, ContractId, ContractStartDate;
```

To use this in your process, you will want something like `where Workers_ID = @Workers_Id` to select the current worker.

The `row_number()` function assigns a sequential number to each row for each worker (because of the `partition by` clause`.  The first row is the one with the highest contract id (because of the`order by` clause).

Comment: great that is exactly what i need and i learned new commands as well. after understanding it i just had to add 'partition by workers_ID, Date' for my purposes. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select sum(h.HoursToWork)
from (select max(contract_ID) contract_ID
      from contracts_table
      where XXX=workers_ID) c
join hours_table h on c.contract_ID = h.contract_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should work:

```
select Workers_ID, sum(CASE WHEN dt1 is null THEN dt2 ELSE dt1 END) from
(select Workers_ID,

   DATEDIFF(DAY,
            ContractStartDate,
            (select top 1 ContractStartDate from yourTable t2
                where t2.Workers_ID=t1.Workers_ID 
                and t2.ContractStartDate>t1.ContractStartDate)
           )  * HoursToWork as dt1,
   DATEDIFF(DAY,
            ContractStartDate,
            GetDate()
           )  * HoursToWork as dt2               
from yourTable t1) a
group by Workers_ID
```

See [fiddler](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85dc9/66)